# Различные результаты с fcom/fcompp и fstatsw

Tags: windows, ассемблер, fasm, fpu

Я только начинаю разбираться с FPUи наткнулся на один интересный момент. Поправьте меня, если какое из следующих утверждений неверно: есть 3 ST регистров (0-7), т.е. с их помощью можно оперировать только 8 числами с плавающей запятой.
Рассматриваемый пример кода:

```
fldz; ST0 = 0
fld1; ST0 = 1, ST1 = 0
fcompp
fstatsw ax
```

В результате, я должен получить 0 в регистре AX. Частично это так, например, если этот код находится вначале кода. Но если он выполняется после нескольких арифметических и не только операций, то его результат начинает зависеть от количества значений, загруженных в регистры ST.

Если ST0 больше ST1:

```
count | AX
------+------
    2 | 4000h
    3 | 3800h
    4 | 3000h
    5 | 2800h
    6 | 2000h
    7 | 1800h
    8 | 1000h
```

Т.е. если у меня в ST регистрах только два элемента, то AX = 4000h; если 3 элемента - 3800h и т.д. Сравнение, если что, всегда ST0 и ST1.

Как такое возможно? Что я упускаю?
Для других типов сравнивания аналогичная картина, но с другими значениями.

Если ST0 равен ST1:

```
count | AX
------+------
    2 | 8000h
    3 | 7800h
    4 | 7000h
    5 | 6800h
    6 | 6000h
    7 | 5800h
    8 | 5000h
```

Если ST0 меньше ST1:

```
count | AX
------+------
    2 | 4100h
    3 | 3900h
    4 | 3100h
    5 | 2900h
    6 | 2100h
    7 | 1900h
    8 | 1100h
```

Окружение:

```
Ассемблер: FASM
Архитектура процессора: x64
Приложение: Windows GUI x86
```

Может, это влияние каких-либо флагов. Если так, то как их сбросить?
Я понимаю, что тут нужно обращать внимание на C3 C2 и C0. И причина, как раз в том, что они не те, что ожидаются.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Поправьте меня, если какое из следующих утверждений неверно: есть 3 ST регистров (0-7)

Регистров у FPU всего 8, и организованы они в виде стека ST0-ST7 (см.отладчик x64Dbg).

> В результате, я должен получить 0 в регистре AX. Частично это так, например, если этот код находится вначале кода. Но если он выполняется после нескольких арифметических и не только операций, то его результат начинает зависеть от количества значений, загруженных в регистры ST.

Загляните в доки Интела том.1 *"Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual Volume 1: Basic Architecture"*. Там в главе(8) описывается FPU, и в частности приводится такой скрин с описанием "Status-Word".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В данном случае интересны лишь биты [13:11] под кличкой **"TOP of Stack"**. В доке выше они описываются так:

> Указатель на вершину стека FPU содержится в битах [13:11] и называется TOP. Они представляют собой двоичное значение от 0 до 7, по кол-ву регистров FPU.

Тогда все ваши значения получаются правильными, и просто являются битами TOP.  Чтобы убедиться, возьмите например первый-же ваш лист, и переведите его в bin.

А вообще, перед использованием FPU его стек обычно очищают - для этого имеется инструкция `FINIT`, которая забивает все 8 регистров нулями. Так-же есть `FCLEX` для очистки мл.байта "Status Word". Старший байт (где лежат Busy, TOP и C0-C3) очищать не нужно, т.к. он на автомате принимает новые значения по текущей инструкции.

Comment: Спасибо за развёрнутый ответ и отдельное спасибо за картинку. Ошибка решилась. Перепроверил код пошагово и проверил состояние ST регистров после каждой команды (да, регистров 8, это у меня была опечатка). В итоге проверка происходила с другими значениями, вместо предполагаемых.

Comment: `FCLEX`, в моём случае не помогал. А `FINIT`, наверное, да, нужно добавить. У меня разницы не было, но мало как это сработает на других машинах.